# Java: Stopping or redeploying application - what happens with objects in memory

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am wondering..

Scenario1) - Simple application run on Eclipse performing some operations in many threads and sleeping sometimes. I have an application started on eclipse, simple Java application that is creating some objects in memmory that are leaking... For example I create a class with static hashmap storing strong references to objects. I am nearly running out of memory and I stop application clicking stop in Eclipse or kill -9 procId. I started that application with some jvm parameters like xms, xmx, maxpermsize. What happens with those created objects in JVM Heap / permgen? As long as the application was alive I had a method where I put strong references to static hashmap keys and it was not GC-ed (I checked it in VisualVM->VisualGC). Now I killed this application, what happens with these obects are they GC-ed immidiatelly or not GC-ed and the Heap allocated by my application is suddenly released without checking strong/weak references? How this mechanism is called?

Scenario2) The same questions as above but it is for example Weblogic application that is being redeployed, Heap and permgen almost full..

Comment: Depends, is the application running in the IDE's JVM or it's own?

Comment: both cases are interesting - does it differ? I run this app in Eclipse RunAs JAva application (some class with main method) or I run JUnit - which JVM it uses then? My eclipse is pointing to jdk7 on my hdd.

Answer (score 0):

For scenario 1: Usually, when you start an application in Eclipse, a new JVM process is started. As soon as the application is stopped, the process also is terminated and the memory is released to the operating system (note, that as soon as the process ends, there is no GC or anything else related to the JVM, because all that stuff only works as long as the JVM is running).

For scenario 2: If an application is redeployed, the application server should release the class loaders and create new ones for the new deployed application. Hence all classes and objects related to the old classloaders should be garbage collected on the next run. This however doesn't always work, e.g. Tomcat has (or had) the problem of full permgen when redeploying an application for several times.

Comment: Thanks, so in case of scenario 1 when I start two such applications then kill only one, then only one process would release memory and the second one would have totally separate jvm's memory structure?